# How to create a draggable, zoomable timeline where users can drag to a specific date on a website?

Tags: javascript, html, timeline

I would like to implement something similar to the timelines shown here:
[timeline1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KG2G.png)
[timeline2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWTGm.png)

In timeline1, a user can drag the timeline and click on a date in it to select it.

In timeline2, users drag the timeline itself and the date is selected based on the middle of the timeline that is displayed. Both timelines are zoomable.

I have searched around a lot for a javascript library with this functionality, but have so far been unable to find anything. Does anyone know of such a library, or a way to implement a timeline like one in the examples?

I am very grateful for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to customize [`<input type="range">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range) like so:

```css
html,body{
  margin:0;
}

input[type='range'] {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 90%;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: white;
  border:2px solid;
  height:40px;
  background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXatz.png); /* this is the background for the slider, replace with an image of the track */
}

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  color: white;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  width: 44.5px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: ew-resize;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOhn7.png); /* this is the image of the dragbar thumb */
}
```

```html
<input type="range">
```

An even *better* way is to use it with hash marks and labels:

```html
<input type="range" list="tickmarks">

<datalist id="tickmarks">
  <option value="0" label="0%"></option>
  <option value="10"></option>
  <option value="20"></option>
  <option value="30"></option>
  <option value="40"></option>
  <option value="50" label="50%"></option>
  <option value="60"></option>
  <option value="70"></option>
  <option value="80"></option>
  <option value="90"></option>
  <option value="100" label="100%"></option>
</datalist>
```

Unfortunately, support for this feature is limited. Specifically (from MDN):

> Currently, no browser fully supports these features. Firefox doesn't support hash marks and labels at all, for example, while Chrome supports hash marks but doesn't support labels. Version 66 (66.0.3359.181) of Chrome supports labels but the `<datalist>` tag has to be styled with CSS as its `display` property is set to none by default, hiding the labels.